# Interpreting the output from profiling with 'system.time'

Tags: r, profiling

In experimenting with a simple form of profiling I was uncertain on how to interpret (no pun intended) the results from the two simple examples below:

```
 data <- c()

 system.time (
     for (i in 1:40000) {
         data[i] <- i^5
     }
 )
user  system elapsed 
4.15    0.24   21.34 


 data <- numeric(40000)

 system.time (
     for (i in 1:40000) {
         data[i] <- i^5
     }
 )
user  system elapsed 
0.22    0.00    0.22
```

More specifically, when attempting to ascertain how much faster one approach is over another, which column(s), i.e., user, system, or elapsed, should I take note of? I initially assumed the 'elapsed' column was most appropriate.

Thanks,

~Caitlin

Comment: This illustrated the difference between building a vector by incrememtal extension and assigning into a preallocated data-object. You do not reference any of the many SO posts that deal with system.time, efficiency, or benchmarking, so I suggest you do more searching.

Comment: More specifically: Look at package `microbenchmark` or one of the other benchmark packages. You might also be interested in the `Rprof` function.

Comment: Also, there's a great chapter on Profiling in Hadley Wickham's Advanced R book. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html